# AWS load balancer requires CNAME for DNS pointer. www.domain is covered, but root domain is not covered by SSL certificate

Tags: dynamic, ip, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have inherited an app on AWS. The load balancer must be distributed, as the DNS name points to

```
www.crowd88.com.    756 IN  CNAME   crowd88-prod-elb-1388110015.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

Now, I can't set the root domain to a CNAME. It wouldn't make sense, and DNS servers wont let you anyway, and the IP of the load balancer is dynamic, so if I set it to the IP of the load balancer at any time, when that IP changes, https://crowd88.com goes nowhere. Also, because the SSL certificate is specifically for www.crowd88.com, https://crowd88.com would never redirect anyway, because the domain is not trusted, so a browser will not follow a redirect instruction from that domain.

That last I can fix by using a good SSL cert such as [this one](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl). However, I still don't understand how I can point the root domain to a dynamically changing IP.

My solution at the moment is to create a digitalocean apache server at US$5 per month with a free letsencrypt certificate which just redirects https://crowd88.com to https://www.crowd88.com, but Amazon must have some solution to this problem. I just can't find anything in their documentation, and AWS provide no support with this account.

Comment: I get the feeling that all the issues go away if you use their Route 53 DNS

Comment: If the above Route 53 DNS is a solution, some advice on exporting DNS records from godaddy to Route 53 would be welcome, as there are many DNS records to export, and anything mistyped could block email or kill google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement where rot domain is in godaddy and sub domain in aws . I have created an SSL/TLS certificate from  certificate manager and assigned to loadbalancer and also godaddy has separate SSL certificate for root domain. For your problem it can be solved using SSL/TLS certificate from  certificate manager in AWS where you can use wild cards like www.crowd.*.com to give the access to all subdomains .
see more information at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html

Comment: Is your root domain a cname record in the DNS? AWS requires the IP of the load balancer to be dynamic. I understand I can use wild card ssl certificates, but that is not the issue. The issue is AWS requires crowd88.com and www.crowd88.com to be CNAMES